# Is storing a token in cookie on front end and placing it in header for all requests safe?

Tags: javascript, token, session-cookies, csrf

My friend says hes using tokens to authenticate but I've only worked with cookies. Is it safe to store the token he returns me upon login in a cookie, and then do this:

```
module.exports.getData = (cookie) => { 
  return $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'account/info',
    beforeSend: (xhr) => {xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', cookie.token);}
  });
};
```

My thinking is because other sites can't access the cookie directly, they couldn't do a CSRF attack, and from what I've read local-storage presents an XSS vulnerability that I'm unfamiliar with. I'm new at this so please be understanding if this is a terrible idea. If this is indeed bad then what would the best practice be?

Comment: to clarify, my friend is building a backend and wants me to do the front

Comment: Why doesn't your friend just put the token in a cookie? Why does your clientside code need the token at all?

Answer (score 0):

He probably means JSON Web Token aka JWT. Those are pretty common nowadays and have good support both server and client side. You can find more information from [JWT](https://jwt.io/) website.

Comment: There are also a lot of good reasons to avoid these: http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/   (this is on top of a history of vulnerabilities in jwt library implementations)

Comment: Perhaps you should include it in your answer? I can't think of a serious security practitioner who recommends JWT.